# Resizable Vue-good-table or Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, resizable

I have a table make with Vue-good-table in Vue.js.

I need to find a way for do it resizable. Something like this. 
https://codepen.io/validide/pen/aOKLNo

Unfortunately, Vue-good-table do not have this option, far as I know. 
https://github.com/xaksis/vue-good-table/issues/226

I tested with JQuery, but I do not want mix Jquery and Vue, and I do not know if a library in Jquery, it will work with this component. I tested but I did not find any.

There is another way in Javascript/css or Vue for do it?

```
<vue-good-table
            @on-select-all="'selectAll'"
            :columns="columns"
            :rows="rows"
            :select-options="{ enabled: true }"
            @on-selected-rows-change="selectionChanged"
            :sort-options="{
              enabled: true
            }"></<vue-good-table>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a workaround? mounted solution doesn't work for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add `mounted` method to your component like this:

```
mounted: function () {
    var thElm;
    var startOffset;

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(
    document.querySelectorAll("table th"),
    function (th) {
        th.style.position = 'relative';

        var grip = document.createElement('div');
        grip.innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
        grip.style.top = 0;
        grip.style.right = 0;
        grip.style.bottom = 0;
        grip.style.width = '5px';
        grip.style.position = 'absolute';
        grip.style.cursor = 'col-resize';
        grip.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
            thElm = th;
            startOffset = th.offsetWidth - e.pageX;
        });

        th.appendChild(grip);
    });

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
        if (thElm) {
            thElm.style.width = startOffset + e.pageX + 'px';
        }
    });

    document.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
        thElm = undefined;
    });
}
```

Comment: This is a really great fix even still! 
If you're still around, do you have any idea how you can add this and also increase the overall width of the table alongside the column width?

Comment: Uhh sorry, just saw your comment, probably the problem is not relevant already, but the solution is simple: 
apply the same behavior but with another query selector (not `table th`, but `table`). Hope it should work

Answer (score 5):

Why not create a renderless wrapping component with your own vanilla JavaScript solution? Something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/thrilleratplay/epcybL4v/

```
(function () {
    var thElm;
    var startOffset;

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(
      document.querySelectorAll("table th"),
      function (th) {
        th.style.position = 'relative';

        var grip = document.createElement('div');
        grip.innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
        grip.style.top = 0;
        grip.style.right = 0;
        grip.style.bottom = 0;
        grip.style.width = '5px';
        grip.style.position = 'absolute';
        grip.style.cursor = 'col-resize';
        grip.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
            thElm = th;
            startOffset = th.offsetWidth - e.pageX;
        });

        th.appendChild(grip);
      });

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
      if (thElm) {
        thElm.style.width = startOffset + e.pageX + 'px';
      }
    });

    document.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
        thElm = undefined;
    });
})();
```

There is no need to use jQuery. You can wrap your table with a custom renderless component and dive deeper into its slot component using `this.$el` and the `document.querySelector`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this library in vanillajs
https://github.com/MonsantoCo/column-resizer

```
<div id="app">
  <table border="1" ref="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>

<script>
    new Vue({
      el: "#app",
      data: {},

      mounted() {
        let resizable = ColumnResizer.default

        new resizable(this.$refs.table, {
          liveDrag:true,
          draggingClass:"rangeDrag",
          gripInnerHtml:"<div class='rangeGrip'></div>",
          minWidth:8
        })
      }
    })
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Wagner/eywraw8t/414137/