# bootstrap Vue table with resizable columns

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-vue

I have table with 20 columns and some cell values can be big. I don't want to spread the sell width too much it harms the aesthetics of the table. Bootstrap Vue provides me with filtering, column wise sorting, sticky headers and other awesome options. but i could not find a way to resize the column width as i want.
There are some solutions such as[Vue-column-resizable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-columns-resizable). But they are not working for me as my table is too big and it will not scroll horizontally as i try to expand a column. I hope My question is clear.
sample of what i am trying to do is below.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-table
      :items="items"
      :fields="fields"
      :sort-by.sync="sortBy"
      :sort-desc.sync="sortDesc"
      sort-icon-left
      responsive="sm"
    ></b-table>

    <div>
      Sorting By: <b>{{ sortBy }}</b>, Sort Direction:
      <b>{{ sortDesc ? 'Descending' : 'Ascending' }}</b>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        sortBy: 'age',
        sortDesc: false,
        fields: [
          { key: 'last_name', sortable: true },
          { key: 'first_name', sortable: true },
          { key: 'age', sortable: true },
          { key: 'isActive', sortable: false },
          { key: 'last_name1', sortable: true },
          { key: 'first_name1', sortable: true },
          { key: 'age1', sortable: true },
          { key: 'isActive1', sortable: false },
          { key: 'last_name2', sortable: true },
          { key: 'first_name2', sortable: true },
          { key: 'ag32', sortable: true },
          { key: 'isActive2', sortable: false },
          { key: 'last_name3', sortable: true },
          { key: 'first_name3', sortable: true },
          { key: 'age3', sortable: true },
          { key: 'isActive3', sortable: false },
          { key: 'last_name4', sortable: true },
          { key: 'first_name4', sortable: true },
          { key: 'age4', sortable: true },
          { key: 'isActive4', sortable: false },

        ],
        items: [
          { isActive: true, age: 40, first_name: 'Dickerson', last_name: 'Macdonald',
            isActive1: false, age1: 21, first_name1: 'Larsen', last_name1: 'Shaw',
            isActive2: false, age2: 21, first_name2: 'Larsen', last_name2: 'Shaw',
            isActive3: false, age3: 21, first_name3: 'Larsen', last_name3: 'Shaw',
            isActive4: false, age4: 21, first_name4: 'Larsen', last_name4: 'Shaw' }

        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52759087/resizable-vue-good-table-or-vue/58281585#58281585

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52759087/resizable-vue-good-table-or-vue/58281585#58281585

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: sadly no, tried a raw javascript table for resizing but it did not serve other purposes.